# Can't access req.user in Node.js server with Auth0/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication, express

I'm using auth0 to  act as my admin panel's login, and it's running great. A problem that I'm having is that in node, I cannot for some reason access 'req.user' as it returns unidentified. This is a pretty basic setup here. I have console logged req.headers and an authentication header is set.

Here is the node app.js file

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var app = express();
    var Parse = require('node-parse-api').Parse;

    var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
    app.Parse = new Parse(options.app_id, options.api_key);
    app.use('/api', routes(app), expressJwt({secret: 'Mode'}));
    app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/public') });
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Here is the AngularJS code.

```
var app = angular.module('EnragedGamers', ['angularMoment', 'ngRoute', 'auth0', 'angular-storage', 'angular-jwt'])
.config(function(authProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'Home'
        })
        .when('/article/:article_id', {
            templateUrl: 'article.html',
            controller: 'Article'
        })
        .when('/admin-panel/login', {
            templateUrl: 'admin-login.html',
            controller: 'Admin-Login'
        })
        .when('/admin-panel', {
            templateUrl: 'admin.html',
            controller: 'Admin',
            requiresLogin: true
        });

    authProvider.init({
        domain: 'enragedgamers.auth0.com',
        clientID: 'MpTkAl4eosjl3SB682ZGSSrJYi03QiZp',
        loginUrl: '/admin-panel/login'
    });

    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['store', function(store) {
        // Return the saved token
        return store.get('token');
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

})
.run(function($rootScope, auth, store, jwtHelper, $location) {
    // This hooks al auth events to check everything as soon as the app starts
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
        var token = store.get('token');
        if (token) {
          if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
            if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
              auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
            }
          } else {
            // Either show the login page or use the refresh token to get a new idToken
            $location.path('/');
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the routes file code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = function(app){

    router.get('/admin/hello', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.user)
        res.status(201).json({'human': 'Hello'})
        console.log(req.body);
    });

    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're missing your secret on the node side and the middle man for actually authenticating.

See https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.use(jwt({ secret: 'your secret key here'}));
```

Comment: Okay so I got it working kind of, but now I need to be able to actually get the users metadata on auth0. The req.user object returns something like this.

{ iss: domain',
  sub: usersid,
  aud: value,
  exp: 1454222026,
  iat: 1454186026 }

Comment: What you need to do is add your userID to the jwt token within the payload  object when you are creating the token. Then when your requests are made on your node server req.user object should have that data within it. Hope that helps. Edit: Check out the Multi-tenancy example in the documentation.

Comment: How exactly would I go about something like that? My apologies, I'm very new to jwt.

Comment: No worries.Wait, is the sub value in the user meta data the actual user id already? I've actually only used JWT in its raw form, (made by the same dev) https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken. Not sure where to go from here. Sorry man.